# About the construction "It is ... that..."

Tags: syntactic-analysis

A reviewer at a journal where I submitted an article writes:

There are too many instances of the awkward construction “It is … that….”

I'd be very grateful if you could explain to me why this construction is awkward.

Comment: 'It is obvious that you need to listen to your boss' and 'It is good that you are listening' are fine. Though you can overdo even acceptable usages. // 'It is / It's John that you need to see' is fine if it's already obvious that you need to see _someone_; otherwise, 'You need to see John' sounds much more natural. // 'It is happy that I am to see you' sounds like something an actor might come out with to show they're Irish.

Comment: Could you give us some examples please. There are lots of constructions that look quite similar. So there's a big difference between clefts "it's Bob that we hate" and extraposed subjects: "It's clear that ....". The first contains a relative clause, the second doesn't ... So some examples would really help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the construction looks awkward as we, as the reader, do not know who the 'It' refers to. It appears some abstract being, but in reality I suspect it is the speaker. In "It's John that you need to see", we know you are referring to John. When we add in the speaker, the other quotes would be - "It is obvious to me, that you need to listen to your boss", "I think it is good that you are listening".

Once we clarify this we can see that the quotes can be made less passive and more active - "You need to listen to your boss", "Good, you're listening" as the reference to the speaker is then implied as they are the one doing the speaking.

I know that it is considered good form when writing some articles to exclusively use passivity, but even with good passivity, we can still tidy up to make the sentence flow better. ie "It's John that you need to see" doesn't need the "that" - "It's John you need to see".

It is understood that good writing ... sorry! I have always understood that good writing is about communicating in as concise a manner as possible. Quote from an unknown book editor "being an author is 50% writing, 50% removing what you have written".

Simple test - Remove a word/words and see if the meaning is still clear to someone who is reading it for the first time.

PS: "It is happy that I am to see you" sounds more Yoda than Irish.